# Rejected transaction

Tags: bitcoin-qt-setup

What means this: "Transaction rejected by our node. Reason: Non-canonical signature: High S Value". It came after trying to send BTC to my new Qt-wallet from old synchronised wallet (version 0.8), which was restored to status about 1 month ago by copying backup wallet.dat file.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to create signatures for transactions. One uses a High S Value and the other a Low S Value.  Since the signature can be malleated by third parties (also see [transaction-malleability](/questions/tagged/transaction-malleability)) to switch the High S to Low S and vice versa, and that changes the transaction id, High S Values have been deprecated for several versions.

You could either malleate the transaction's signature to Low S and republish it, or you could just import the `wallet.dat` into the new Bitcoin-Qt that you're trying to send the funds to anyway.

Be sure to create a backup of the new `wallet.dat` before you import the old.

Answer (score 0):

bitcoin 0.8.x does not follow new bitcoin consensus rules and sends invalid transactions sometimes. modern nodes do not accept these transactions and show you an error message.

this is an explanation for the question "what means?"

there is no question "what should I do to...?" here.